# How to draw selectable lines using java swt

Tags: java, onclick, swt, mouseevent

I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction. I am writing a code using JAVA SWT, where i have 2 composites and a connector connecting those two composites. I want to be able to detect mouse click event on both the composites and the connector. The mouse click on the composite is achieved but i am not sure how to achieve mouse click on the connector. I am drawing the connector using GC. The following is the code which draws the line

```
GC gc = new GC(composite);
gc.fillRectangle(composite.getClientArea());
gc.setForeground(composite.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
gc.setLineWidth(3);
gc.drawLine(x,y,X,Y);
```

The above code draws a line between the two composite (Taking a starting point and an ending point). Now, I want to be able to detect when the user clicks on the line which is connecting the two composites. 
Is there any better way to connect those 2 composite which will give me the ability to detect mouse click.

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me towards the right direction.

Thanks, 
Rohith

Comment: Are you reinventing the wheel to learn, or just for fun? You could use  Zest http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/